# how to make bins by different values in a variable in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set like below and i want to make them into different bins by using the values of smstext

bindata

```
  userid      smstext
0 vodafone     56
1 airtel       101
2 reliance     505
3 tata         1500
4 mts          10
```

What i need is if sms text value is between 0-10 the binname should be 10,
if sms text value is between 11-50 the bin name should be 50,
if sms text value is between 51-100 the binname should be 100,
if sms text value is between 101-500 the binname should be 500,
if sms text value is between 500-1000 the binname should be 1000,
if sms text value is above 1000 the binname should be 1001.

Expected output:

bindata

```
  userid      smstext   bin
0 vodafone     56       100
1 airtel       101      500
2 reliance     505      1000
3 tata         1500     1001
4 mts          10        10
```

I can solve by using np.where and np.logical but i need a simple way to do the above in python.please help me on this.....

Comment: what type of data set is it? numpy?

Comment: pandas.core.series.series

Answer (score 1):

The code to convert one value of smstext to its bin would be

```
def convert_to_bin(v, bins, other):
    for b in bins:
        if v <= b:
            return b

    return other
```

And could be called (for your values) as

```
convert_to_bin(somevalue, [10, 50, 100, 1000], 1001)
```

Some examples:

```
In [5]: convert_to_bin(1, [10, 50, 100, 1000], 1001)
Out[5]: 10

In [6]: convert_to_bin(51, [10, 50, 100, 1000], 1001)
Out[6]: 100

In [7]: convert_to_bin(31, [10, 50, 100, 1000], 1001)
Out[7]: 50

In [8]: convert_to_bin(2031, [10, 50, 100, 1000], 1001)
Out[8]: 1001
```

Then you just have to add the results to the dataset.

Comment: i have large number of values,how can insert all of them in the place of somevalue and how can i save the each iteration result

Comment: If your list of values is in `smstext`, then `[convert_to_bin(v, [10,50,100,1000],1001) for v in smstext]` will convert them all. Adding them to your original list depends on how it is represented

Comment: i undrestand it but not totally ,can you edit your code that how can i write the code for the above data...please

Comment: I don't use panda, so not really. And it depends on how you have read your table into memory. The documentation should show you how to add a new column to a table. The list comprehension I gave you will generate all the values for the new column. Any example I created using your data isn't likely to be something you can just plug in to your existing code. That's why I wrote the conversion as a function

Comment: And it looks like you are using a pandas.DataFrame not pandas.Series

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `itertools.groupby`.

```
import itertools

for dataInGroup, group in itertools.groupby(dataToBeGrouped, grouperFunction):
  print group, dataInGroup
```

groupby takes a function that determines the group of a data item and then returns an iterator that loops through each group label and the items in that group.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to pandas but it seems you want the [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.cut.html) function.

```
smstext = np.array([56, 101, 505, 1500, 10])
bins = pd.cut(smstext, [0, 11, 51, 101, 501, 1000, float('inf')], 
    right=False, labels=[10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 1001])
```

This returns

```
  100
  500
 1000
 1001
   10
```

If for some reason you wanted to write this function yourself rather than using pandas, it would look something like this:

```
def cut(iter, bins):
    def categorise(item):
        for right in bins:
            if item < right:
                return right - 1
        return bins[-1]

    return [categorise(item) for item in iter]

print(cut(smstext, [0, 11, 51, 101, 501, 1001]))
```